# Factorio graphics bug; black background

Tags: factorio

Since a few days everytime I start Factorio on my PC there is no map background (everything except items like ores is black). When I move the mouse randomly over some buildings the information tab is still popping up.

What I already did:
I tried to fix this error by reinstalling the game, it did not work. I checked the local game files with Steam, it didn't detect any issues. I changed the graphic settings to different configurations (fullscreen/windowed, low/high resolutions, details etc.)

My hardware:
I do not think my graphics card or other components are causing this. I'm running a GTX 1080 from Asus with the latest drivers. No recent hardwarechanges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this announcement](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40375), it's an issue with the latest Nvidia drivers.

> To workaround this issue, open the Factorio properties in steam, and set the launch options to:
>
> `--max-texture-size=16384`

Nvidia [has said](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40375#p239514) the issue will be fixed in the next driver release

Comment: You can also rollback your display driver to a different version and see if that fixes it also.  This is faster though.